# Snapping UI sprite in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbXiC.png)

Is there any way to snap UI sprite vertex? Holding "V" does not work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Checking Unity's Documentation is good start when you run into an issue. I checked the documentation, which can be found here: [Modifying Sprite Vertices via Script](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-vertices.html).

Reading the documentation you can grab a Sprites Vertices using a Vector2 Array.

```cs
//Fetch the Sprite and vertices from the SpriteRenderer
Sprite sprite = m_SpriteRenderer.sprite;
Vector2[] spriteVertices = sprite.vertices;
```

You can draw using the vertices by following this and viewing them in scene view

```cs
// Show the sprite triangles
void DrawDebug()
{
    Sprite sprite = m_SpriteRenderer.sprite;

    ushort[] triangles = sprite.triangles;
    Vector2[] vertices = sprite.vertices;
    int a, b, c;

    // draw the triangles using grabbed vertices
    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i = i + 3)
    {
        a = triangles[i];
        b = triangles[i + 1];
        c = triangles[i + 2];

        //To see these you must view the game in the Scene tab while in Play mode
        Debug.DrawLine(vertices[a], vertices[b], Color.red, 100.0f);
        Debug.DrawLine(vertices[b], vertices[c], Color.red, 100.0f);
        Debug.DrawLine(vertices[c], vertices[a], Color.red, 100.0f);
    }
}
```

Snapping the vertices together through the use of scripting, however, does seem overly complicated depending on what these are for. Given this, it would be useful to know why you want to do this? If these sprites are static and unmoving or only used for a short period it may be much easier to manually align them in the Scene view.

Another method could be to use ProGrid, which is a Unity Package that allows you to turn on snapping in your scene and is very useful for aligning gameobjects; this also allows the amount of snapping to be changed.

Find it by going to *Window -> Package Manager*. Note that you may need to turn on *preview packages* to find it.